# How to use Selenium with chromedriver inside Docker in Mac M1 ARM?

Tags: docker, kotlin, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use the Chrome inside my Docker for my Selenium project.
Here is how I start Docker

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
```

Then, in my code, I'm trying to use the `RemoteWebDriver` to connect to my Docker

```
val chromeOptions = ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
val url = URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
webDriver = RemoteWebDriver(url, chromeOptions)
val baseUrl = "https://www.google.com"
webDriver.get(baseUrl)
webDriver.quit()
```

But then, I'm receiving response code 500 error from Selenium.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'c3d9edcf7df3', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.5.1', java.version: '11.0.16.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --headless], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --headless], extensions: []}}}]
Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --headless], extensions: []}}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
```

How can I use Docker for Selenium?

My Selenium version:

- selenium-java:4.8.1
- selenium-chrome-driver:4.8.1

I also tried to upgrade to the latest Selenium version which is:

- selenium-java:4.12.1
- selenium-chrome-driver:4.12.1

EDIT:
After adding the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` and `--remote-debugging-port=9222`
here is my new Error message

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: '419674405ad2', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.5.1', java.version: '11.0.16.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --headless, --disable-extensions, --remote-debugging-port=9222], extensions: []}}]}]
Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --headless, --disable-extensions, --remote-debugging-port=9222], extensions: []}}
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:163)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:143)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could connect to `localhost:4444` and check the gui normally.
>
> After further browsing, seems like the root cause is I'm running it in MacOs m1, which is arm. The current docker image is for amd.
> I am trying to find the docker image for the arm now

Good point.

You could try running the Docker container using emulation for the x86_64 platform if an ARM-based image is not available. You can do this by specifying the [`--platform` flag](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/#building-multi-platform-images) when running the Docker container.

```bash
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 \
           --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
```

The `--platform linux/amd64` flag instructs Docker to emulate the AMD64 (x86_64) architecture on your ARM-based machine. This is particularly useful when you want to run containers that are not yet available for ARM64 architecture.
Docker Desktop for Mac (Apple Silicon) supports this emulation through Apple's Rosetta 2, which allows you to run Intel-based containers on ARM by translating the x86_64 CPU instructions to ARM64.

But, of course, that emulation might incur a performance hit.

---

[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233656/mark) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77163029/how-to-use-selenium-with-chromedriver-inside-docker-in-mac-m1-arm/77182628#comment136260562_77182628)

> Should running Docker with the following command in mac m1
>
> ```
> docker run --platform linux/arm64 -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 \
>            --shm-size="2g" seleniarm/standalone-chromium:latest.
> ```
>
> Have been tested to working normally fine.

---

As noted by [djmonki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11543023/djmonki) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77163029/how-to-use-selenium-with-chromedriver-inside-docker/77182628?noredirect=1#comment136092273_77182628)

> That does not work for the selenium provided containers.
> It is something to do with the container platform and the fact that selenium are using the intel64 bit chromedriver within the container.
>
> In the end we moved to using the seleniarm docker images which can be found here: [`hub.docker.com/u/seleniarm`](https://hub.docker.com/u/seleniarm)

For example: [`seleniarm/standalone-docker`](https://hub.docker.com/r/seleniarm/standalone-docker): Multi-arch container images for Selenium, to run on ARM hardware and x86_64.

---

Original answer:

You may need to add some [more arguments](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/) to `ChromeOptions` to ensure stable execution inside the Docker container.

```kotlin
val chromeOptions = ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
```

1. `--disable-gpu`: Disables the GPU hardware acceleration. That is generally useful in headless environments.
2. `--disable-dev-shm-usage`: That flag will force Chrome to use disk instead of `/dev/shm` for shared memory, which may resolve crashing issues.
3. `--remote-debugging-port=9222`: see [Chrome DevTools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/)

Note: a `SessionNotCreatedException` is usually indicative of a mismatch between Chrome and ChromeDriver versions, or it can also be due to limited resources available on the system. Since you are using a Docker image for Selenium Standalone Chrome, the version mismatch is unlikely. You can, however, verify this by checking the logs when the Docker container starts up.

Taking into account the additional [ChromeOptions](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) and Docker configurations, the updated code should look like:

```kotlin
val chromeOptions = ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
val url = URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
webDriver = RemoteWebDriver(url, chromeOptions)
val baseUrl = "https://www.google.com"
webDriver.get(baseUrl)
webDriver.quit()
```

Try running your Selenium test again with these changes. If the issue persists, check the Docker logs for the Selenium container to gain more insight into what might be causing the problem (`docker logs <container_id>`).

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I was feeling unwell yesterday. I have tried adding all those arguments, but its still not working. I could connect to localhost:4444 and check the gui normally. After further browsing, seems like the root cause is I'm running it in MacOs m1, which is arm. the current docker image is for amd. Im trying to find the docker image for the arm now

Comment: @Mark I hope you will feel better soon. For your problem, while you are searching an image for ARM, you could try `--platform linux/amd64` for testing. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Mark my project hit the same issue. Von C is correct on emulation of the docker container, but that does not work for the selenium provided containers. It is something to do with the container platform and the fact that selenium are using the intel64 bit chromedriver within the container. In the end we moved to using the `seleniarm` docker images which can be found here: https://hub.docker.com/u/seleniarm

Comment: @djmonki Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @djmonki Thank you VonC and djmonki. I think this is already the best answer for this question. the answer is that the current standalone image is not compatible with arm. Even though I'm encountering another issue with seleniarm, but it would be another question. Thank you for both of the answers

Comment: hi @VonC to update, should running Docker with the following command in mac m1 `docker run --platform linux/arm64 -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" seleniarm/standalone-chromium:latest`. Have been tested to working normally fine

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `--disable-dev-shm-usage` argument just after `--no-sandbox`:

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

If it doesn't work, try to add also this:

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
```

Comment: I tried to add the `--disable-dev-shm-usage`, now the error message that I get is different. it is showing `chrome not reachable`. my selenium should be the latest one already

Comment: @Mark Please provide full log for this new error. Also, check if your local chromedriver version is compatible with the Selenium version inside the container.

Comment: Hi Alberto, I have included the new error message into the question. Do I need a chromedriver in my local machine? I thought that by using Docker, I could just use both the chrome and the chromedriver inside the Docker. Am i wrong about this?

Comment: What happens if you open `http://localhost:4444` from your host machine (traditional browser), obviously before/without trying to run `RemoteWebDriver`? Does it open?

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply. yes I could connect to localhost:4444 and check the gui. I could confirm when running the docker, there is no error message. After further browsing, I'm suspecting that the main issue is that I'm running it in my MacOs m1, which is arm. and the current docker image is for amd. I'm trying to find a docker image for arm now.

Answer (score 0):

Please post docker logs, it looks like you are not able to connect to hub. make sure your hub is running on localhost on port 4444. you can also check it by running http://localhost:4444/ui on browser.
try to run selenium server image using docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome.